# Reactjs fullcalendar component and trying to add resource plugin and getting Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add resource plugin in full calendar reactjs component and getting this error **Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.**. here is my snippet of code. i also tried @fullcalendar/resource-timeline, @fullcalendar/resource-common etc. also refered every documentation in fullcalendar official website. any expert help will be appriciated.

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; // needed for dayClick
import resourceCommonPlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-common"; // needed for dayClick

import "./styles.css";

// must manually import the stylesheets for each plugin
import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
    calendarWeekends: true,
    calendarEvents: [
      // initial event data
      { title: "Event Now", start: new Date() }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app">
        <div className="demo-app-top">
          <button onClick={this.toggleWeekends}>toggle weekends</button>&nbsp;
          <button onClick={this.gotoPast}>go to a date in the past</button>
          &nbsp; (also, click a date/time to add an event)
        </div>
        <div className="demo-app-calendar">
          <FullCalendar
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            header={{
              left: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
            }}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
            weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
            events={this.state.calendarEvents}
            dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  toggleWeekends = () => {
    this.setState({
      // update a property
      calendarWeekends: !this.state.calendarWeekends
    });
  };

  gotoPast = () => {
    let calendarApi = this.calendarComponentRef.current.getApi();
    calendarApi.gotoDate("2000-01-01"); // call a method on the Calendar object
  };

  handleDateClick = arg => {
    if (confirm("Would you like to add an event to " + arg.dateStr + " ?")) {
      this.setState({
        // add new event data
        calendarEvents: this.state.calendarEvents.concat({
          // creates a new array
          title: "New Event",
          start: arg.date,
          allDay: arg.allDay
        })
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: A similar question was asked soon after yours...maybe the answer would help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571599/fullcalendar-error-please-import-the-top-level-fullcalendar-lib-before-attempti . I don't now for sure, I'm not familiar with `import` in JS very much, but it sounds like a similar issue.

Comment: @ADyson i already tried solution which they answred.

Comment: And the result was...?

Comment: result was same

Comment: i did solved this issues by updating node v12.18.1.